# Trigger getting Inactive Automatically

Tags: apex, trigger

I got a very weird scenario. I was writing a simple trigger on my Case object in Dev ORG. And I have In-Active all trigger on Case and have only 1 before trigger attach to my Case object. I have activated the trigger and create a New case (Insert trigger to work) and later I can see my trigger not functioning as expected, so I check I trigger status and its showing its In-Active.

The same scenario happened 2-3 times, do you know a reason behind it. The trigger is for just populating a Custom Description field (Warranty Summary) based on Custom fields in Case object.

```
trigger WarrantSummary on Case (before insert) { 
    String endingComment = 'Have a nice Day!!';

    for(Case myCase: Trigger.new){
        if(myCase.Product_Purchase_Date__c != NULL){
            String purchaseDate        = myCase.Product_Purchase_Date__c.format();
            String createdDate         = DateTime.now().format(); 
            Integer warrantyDays       = myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c.intValue(); 
            Decimal warrantyPer        = (100*(myCase.Product_Purchase_Date__c.daysBetween(Date.today())
                                               /myCase.Product_Total_Warranty_Days__c).setScale(2));
            Boolean hasExtndWrnty      = myCase.Product_Has_Extended_Warranty__c; 

            myCase.Warranty_Summary__c = 'Product purchased on ' +purchaseDate+ 
                ' and case created on ' +createdDate+ '.\n'+
                'Warranty is for ' +warrantyDays+  
                ' Days and is ' +warrantyPer+ '% through its warranty period.\n'+
                'Extended warranty: ' +hasExtndWrnty+ '\n'+    
                endingComment; 
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue for this? In any chance a Trigger can be automatically In-Active?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you coding simultaneosly from UI, Devconsole or Force.com IDE?
Suppose your trigger was initially deactivated. So if you have activated a trigger via Salesforce UI and that trigger was already open in Dev console.
Now when you save in devconsole it will get deactivated again.

Solution: Make trigger Active and Again refresh the Dev Console(Any IDE).

Do you have Continuous Integration in progress, I believe the metadata file isnt updated in your local code, and hence after every commit it makes trigger inactive.

Comment: Ya thanks Pranay, it looks like you are correct. I have opened the trigger from UI and Devconsole and might caused the issue. I have closed the UI and can see now all normal. Thanks a lot for your help in this to understand